# Find coordinates of partial image of an image

Tags: image, matlab, find, coordinates

I am searching for a way to find the location of a button on my screen using matlab. Now i have created the following code for this:
With this code i make a screenshot of my computer, load it in matlab and make it double. 
Then do the same with a target image, the image that needs to be found on my screen, and then try to match this to find matrix to the total matrix and display the coordinates of the top left corner of this image.
The problem is that with this method and a screen resolution of 1920*1080 it takes about 15 min to go trough this full proces.

So my question is, is there an easier/faster way to find the coördinates(or the center of) an image on my screen, or within another image? So far i have found none, even when using the image processing toolbox.

```
clear all
close all
robo = java.awt.Robot;
t = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
rectangle = java.awt.Rectangle(t.getScreenSize());
image = robo.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
filehandle = java.io.File('screencapture.png');
javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(image,'png',filehandle);
scrimg=im2double(imread('screencapture.png')); % screenshot
sfimg=im2double(imread('searchfor.png')); % image to look for

[mA,nA,zA] = size(sfimg);
[mB,nB,zB] = size(scrimg);
F = zeros((mB-mA+1)*(nB-nA+1),3);
k = 0;
for p = 1:mB-mA+1
 for q = 1:nB-nA+1
     for r = 1:zB-zA+1
         iets=[p q r];
         disp(iets)
      if all(all(sfimg==scrimg(p:p+mA-1,q:q+nA-1,r:r+zA-1)))
       k = k + 1;
       F(k,:) = [p,q,r];
      end
     end
 end
end
F(k+1:end,:) = [];
```

Comment: Have a look at `xcorr2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following links:

- http://repository.asu.edu/items/15110
- http://repository.asu.edu/attachments/94025/content//tmp/package-fN0ldX/Velocimeter.pdf
- http://repository.asu.edu/attachments/94026/content//tmp/package-fN0ldX/ThesisPresentationr2.pdf

I did 2d tracking from videos in matlab against some very particular geometries.  It was radically faster than 15 minutes.  The part you are interested in is "measure on image".

The basic idea is that you can use fourier-domain 2d operations, a "max" and some local polynomial fitting to get reliable sub-pixel alignment.

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

A quicker way is to instead of searching for the entire image is to take a smaller subset of pixels say:

```
n=4;
SegmentOfImage=sfimg(1:(mA/n),1:(nA/n));
```

and search for that segment. Obviously as **n** increases the algorithm would be quicker.

If you want to then make sure that it was actually that segment you can make another comparison on the whole image but now you know the index to start with.

Note:
1) This algorithm can actually take longer if there are a lot of objects with identical pixels to

> SegmentOfImage.

2) Also, I believe that this code in general would work only if the matrices are exactly the same. For example if the size of **sfimg** is not the same as **scrimg** it would fail.

Hope this helps